# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: character to number conversion error while using variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I know its been asked a lot but didn't know how to apply it in a variable;

this is my code

```
DECLARE

Main_time_elap varchar2(1000);
time_elap  varchar2(1000);
time_elape number(5);

BEGIN

    main_time_elap:=to_char(systimestamp,'HH24:MI:SS');

    time_elap:=to_char(systimestamp,'HH24:MI:SS');
    time_elape:=to_number(time_elap)-to_number(main_time_elap);
    --time_elape :=time_elap-main_time_elap ;

END;
```

Comment: Isn't obvious that an expression with non-numeric characters cannot be converted to a numeric one ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I know how to read but i tried to change it to number then i tried to cast also i tried to extract it , but still get error , its been time since i worked with oracle

Comment: What to you expect from `to_number('16:23:30')`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit actually it was `time_elape :=time_elap-main_time_elap ;` the time_elap is varchar2 declared so i though changin it to number then assign it as number might work . as for the 2nd comment well I extracted the minutes and seconds in varcahr2 thats why didnt work, my goal is to the get the seconds between two inserts to check how much it took.

Comment: You can subtract dates directly. See: [What is the equivalent of DATEDIFF in Oracle?](https://www.complexsql.com/oracle-datediff-function-examples/). Do this with dates. Not with varchar2, not with number!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much simpler:

```
DECLARE

Main_time_elap TIMESTAMP;
time_elap  TIMESTAMP;
time_elape INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
sec_elape NUMBER;

BEGIN
       main_time_elap := systimestamp;

       time_elap := systimestamp;
       time_elape := time_elap - main_time_elap;    
       sec_elape := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time_elape);
end;
/
```